# Unsure about this review audit (late-answers/28986244)

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits

I was going through the Late Answers review queue, when the [second thing I reviewed was an audit (`late-answers/28986244`).](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28986244)

I upvoted the post, as it did seem to contain potentially useful information. These kinds of audits where I do feel there is good information have blocked me from reviewing twice (3 days and 7 days if I remember correctly).

Answer:
<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

> I had such issue after I've upgrade to 0.13 from 0.12 for the resource I've removed long time ago. **terraform state rm resourcename fixed a problem for me.**

This seems to provide a possible answer to the question.

Comment: That answer needs _at least_ an edit. The fluff at the beginning can be removed and `terraform state rm resourcename` should be formatted correctly.

Comment: You upvoted a deleted answer, had you opened the question in another tab, you would have realized it was an audit.  The answer contains absolutely no details and thus should have been submitted as a comment or modified to include more information by its author.  The answer is extremely low quality for that reason

Comment: @SecurityHound *"The answer contains absolutely no details and thus should have been submitted as a comment or modified to include more information by its author" - I dunno if you didn't just read the post or not, OP even clearly emboldened the relevant part of the answer for you, the answer is an answer, it's just poorly formatted. Saying it contains "absolutely no details" is speaking trash, it does contain details, they're just poorly presented

Comment: I absolutely read the quote.  It’s a commentary at best.  It’s not an actual answer to the question.  The actual answer isn’t important, your improper review of a deleted answer, is the problem.  Yes; You improperly handled the audit.  The audit is legitimate since it catcher users who are clicking to quickly.

Comment: It's an answer but needs editing to be a good one.